# Wso2 api manager. Add custom property to throttilng event message payload

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 API Manager.
My application has customized identity server that adds new attribute to messageContext, for example `String color="red"`.
Now I need to add throttling with this attribute by creating a custom siddhi query. It accepts only standard key templates:
**resourceKey, userId, apiContext, apiVersion, appTenant, apiTenant, appId, clientIp.**
Unfortunately I can't find out how to pass custom attribute to throttle event receiver and throttle request stream.
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to set this value as a header parameter, you can use Advanced policies with a Header parameter condition.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/rate-limiting/adding-new-throttling-policies/#adding-a-new-advanced-throttling-policy

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Probably it will be the best solution. Unfortunately i can't find where to add new headers on global level. Should I use mediators, handlers or maybe somewhere in carbon? (I'm using wso2 api manager 2.5 version)

Comment: You can configure mediation extension sequences to  the APIs of a specific tenant at a [global level](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Adding+Mediation+Extensions#AddingMediationExtensions-Creatingglobalextensions).